# How do I return my ViewModel after going through for-loops?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have a ViewModel with these fields:

```
List<Question> questions;
List<Answer> answers;
```

where Question holds an `ICollection<Answer>` and each answer holds a question, EF migrating style.

I'm showing the data in the view but afterwards I'd like to bring it as a parameter to my post-parameter. 
The ViewModel holds following data:
3 questions
5 answers in each question

My View looks like this:

```
@model SurveyAPI.Models.ViewModels.ShowSurveyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.questions.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => Model.questions[i].QuestionText, new { style = "font-weight : bold" })

    for (int ii = 0; ii <= Model.questions[i].Answers.Count; ii++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(p => Model.answers[ii].Id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => Model.answers[ii].AnswerText)
        @Html.HiddenFor(p => Model.answers[ii].Question)
    }
    <hr />
}

<input type="submit" />
}
```

But what I'm submitting isn't everything.
Instead it holds:

3 questions (as it should)

5 answers (only from the last question - I obviously want all 15 answers).

Each answer (the 5 I am receiving) holds no question to them even though that there's data in the Hidden field to the question.

What on earth am I doing wrong and how do I recieve the exact same object as the model is now in my post-method?

Answer (score 1):

The inputs in inner loop don't reference question object, so it always starts from 0. They all have same names (as they start from 0 for every question) so only those from first iteration of outer loop are used.
To fix it, inner loop should look something like this:

```
for (int ii = 0; ii <= Model.questions[i].Answers.Count; ii++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.questions[i].Answers[ii].Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.questions[i].Answers[ii].AnswerText)
    @Html.HiddenFor(p => p.questions[i].Answers[ii].Question)
}
```

Each HiddenFor and TextBoxFor should have reference do questions[i], so input names are rendered unique and post'ed corectly.

If You want to have separate property for question and answer, inner loop variable cannot start from 0, for example it should look like this:

```
@{ int index = 0; }
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.questions.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(p => Model.questions[i].QuestionText, new { style = "font-weight : bold" })

    for (int ii = 0; ii <= Model.questions[i].Answers.Count; ii++, index++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(p => Model.answers[index].Id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(p => Model.answers[index].AnswerText)
        @Html.HiddenFor(p => Model.answers[index].Question)
    }
    <hr />
}
```

Comment: I can't get the index from p.questions[i].Answers since questions holds an ICollection of answers. I can't index through an ICollection.

Comment: Man it works! I'll have to look at it tomorrow, it's 4AM and I just couldn't let it go. Thanks dude, you just saved the last hours of my night.